# How to pass a URL parameter to FormPage?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, parameters, api

I'm trying to pass a parameter on a [FormPage](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormPage.html). I know that passing parameters on a [APIFunction](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/APIFunction.html) works, like:

```
https://wolframcloud.com/...?x=5&y=10
```

But, I see no way of doing this in a `FormPage`, is there anyway I can pass the parameter to the `FormPage`'s fields?

```
https://wolframcloud.com/...?id=myId
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation shows using `Apply` to allow passing every parameter on `FormPage` via `APIFunction`, as in:

```
CloudDeploy[APIFunction @@ FormPage["x" -> "String", Identity]]
```

But if you'd like to pass fewer parameters via `APIFunction` than are used in your `FormPage`, then you'll want wrap `APIFunction` around `FormPage`, as in the example below:

```
CloudDeploy[
 APIFunction [{"filter" -> "String"}, 
  FormPage[
   {"image" -> "Image", "filter" -> ImageEffect[]}
   , ImageEffect[#image, #filter] &
   , AppearanceRules -> {"Title" -> "Wolf(g)ram"}
  ]
 ]
]
```

Then, in the above example, you pass just the `filter` parameter via the API:

```
https://wolframcloud.com/...?filter=ColorBoosting
```